# Select all the rows based on a column value pandas

Tags: python-3.x, select, pandas, dataframe

Hi I need to select all the rows based on a column value, either store it in a new variable or make a new dataframe and save it into csv with no headers just the info.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print(df)
#      0      1  2   3
# 0  Gm#    one  0   0
# 1  922    one  1   2
# 2  933    two  2   4
# 3  952  three  3   6
# 4  Gm#    two  4   8
# 5  960    two  5  10
# 6  963    one  6  12
# 7  999  three  7  14
```

So I want a new data frame based on a condition of the first column. I only want to grab the rows in a range `>= 900 & <=999`. So desired output:

I want to store it in a csv with no indexes.

```
  print (df2)
  922    one  1   2
  933    two  2   4
  952  three  3   6
  960    two  5  10
  963    one  6  12
  999  three  7  14
```

I tried this: Problem I am getting I can't figure out how to convert a hole column into integers..or maybe there is a easier way to do it by just reference the hole data frame instead checked on various articles on stack overflow and YouTube videos but just can't get it right. Any ideas I will gladly appreciate it.

```
#df[x]= data[x][(data[x]['0'].astype(np.int64))] need to find a away to convert the column [0] into integer for it evaluate
#df2 = data[i]([(data['0'] >= 900) & (data['0'] <= 999)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) first column selected by position by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)  and then add condition `(data['0'].notnull())`, because not numeric values are converted to `NaN`. Last use [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) with parameter `index=False` for removing `index` and `header=None` for removing header:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
{'1': {0: 'one', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'two', 5: 'two', 6: 'one', 7: 'three'}, 
'0': {0: 'Gm', 1: '922', 2: '933', 3: '952', 4: 'Gm', 5: '960', 6: '963', 7: '999'}, 
'3': {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12, 7: 14}, 
'2': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7}})

print data

     0      1  2   3
0   Gm    one  0   0
1  922    one  1   2
2  933    two  2   4
3  952  three  3   6
4   Gm    two  4   8
5  960    two  5  10
6  963    one  6  12
7  999  three  7  14
```

```
data.iloc[:, 0] = pd.to_numeric(data.iloc[:, 0], errors='coerce')
print data
       0      1  2   3
0    NaN    one  0   0
1  922.0    one  1   2
2  933.0    two  2   4
3  952.0  three  3   6
4    NaN    two  4   8
5  960.0    two  5  10
6  963.0    one  6  12
7  999.0  three  7  14


df1 = data[(data['0'] >= 900) & (data['0'] <= 999) & (data['0'].notnull())]
print df1
       0      1  2   3
1  922.0    one  1   2
2  933.0    two  2   4
3  952.0  three  3   6
5  960.0    two  5  10
6  963.0    one  6  12
7  999.0  three  7  14


df1.to_csv('file', index=False, header=None)
```

EDIT by comment:

You can try:

```
for i in range(0, len(tables)): 
    df = tables[i]
    df.replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace='½',value='.5') 
    df.iloc[:, 0] = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:, 0], errors='coerce') 
    df1 = df[(df.iloc[:, 0] >= 900) & (df['0'] <= 999) & (df['0'].notnull())]
    print (df1)
```

Comment: hey I am getting this error I just change the pieces of what you gave me and getting this error.

    tables[i].iloc[:, 0] = tables[i].to_numeric(tables[i].iloc[:, 0], errors='coerce')
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2669, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numeric'

Comment: But I dont use `tables[i]`, but `tables`

Comment: Please check my solution, I add testing DataFrame.

Comment: Hey it works great but I don't  understand when I replace the dataframe for the one I have it throws me indentation error

    df1 = tables[i][(tables[i]['0'] >= 900) & (tables[i]['0'] <= 999) & (tables[i]['0'].notnull())]

The thing is I scrape a lot of tables so thats why I have a for but it checks condition on tables.

Comment: I use many rows, because I hate scrollbars in code. But you can use `data = pd.DataFrame({'1': {0: 'one', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'two', 5: 'two', 6: 'one', 7: 'three'}, '0': {0: 'Gm', 1: '922', 2: '933', 3: '952', 4: 'Gm', 5: '960', 6: '963', 7: '999'}, '3': {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10, 6: 12, 7: 14}, '2': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7}})
` what is same as in solution.

Comment: Thank you for accepting. You can upvote too - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.

Comment: can you help me indent this I don't know how to get it right     
<blink>
       for i in range(0, len(tables)):
       tables[i].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace='½',value='.5')
       tables[i].iloc[:, 0] = pd.to_numeric(tables[i].iloc[:, 0], errors='coerce')
       df1 = tables[i][(tables[i]['0'] >= 900) & (tables[i]['0'] <= 999)]
       print (df1)
    </blink> @jezrael

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111781/discussion-between-herrington-and-jezrael).